# HFFSWorkBook download(Apache POI) + servlet response

Tags: excel, servlets, stream, apache-poi

I want to download an .xls file with content in it. 
This is the method that I have written to process the .xls file according to my requirements and then download it.

```
 public static void readDataFromResponse(String csvData, String fileName,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
    if(!csvData.isEmpty()){
        BufferedReader br = null;
        byte[] binaryData = csvData.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        HSSFWorkbook workBook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workBook.createSheet(fileName);
          // do something to insert values into excel.
        }

        response.setHeader("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(binaryData.length));
        response.setContentType("application/ms-excel");
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition",String.join("","attachment; filename=" + fileName + ".xls"));
        response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "public, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

       //XLS file is downloaded but it is in binary. Not human readable
        OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        workBook.write(outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
    }
```

With this code the excel is exported however the content is not readable.I get the binary representation of the workbook. How to export Excel with data that is readable?

Comment: What isn't working with your current code?

Comment: The output in the excel is binary data.. It is not human readable. When I try the following : `ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); workBook.write(bos); bos.close(); byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray(); response.getOutputStream().write(bytes );` still the content in the excel file is not readable.

Answer (score 2):

You need set the proper values of HttpResponse object

Example

For .Xls file

```
response.setHeader("Content-Type", application/vnd.ms-excel);
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

For Excel2007 and above .xlsx files

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");    
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
```